# How to avoid BigQuery refresh token expiry

Tags: google-bigquery, azure-data-factory

I am trying to bring the data from GCP Bigquery to Azure data lake using Azure data factory. I was able to setup and was able to bring the data into Azure. But my problem is, the GCP refresh token is keep on expiring.

1. How to avoid GCP refresh token expiry?
2. How to generate new refresh token from ADF every time we load the data?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same issue. I Followed the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-bigquery?tabs=data-factory#using-user-authentication) where it is recommended the tutorial indicated by @Veikko. On this tutorial and during my short research, everyone establish that the refresh_token won't expire. During my test, the refresh_token provided me access during the day. Once the day finished, the access is revoked.

The solution to my issue was to use [ServiceAuthentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-bigquery?tabs=data-factory#using-service-authentication). The problem is you will require a **Self-hosted Integration Runtime**. You just need to configure a Service Account on BigQuery. This will provide you and email and a .p12 file that you need to copy on the machine where you installed the integration runtime and done!

My suspect for the reason is that I use multi-factor authentication and VPN to grant access, and it may be the root cause. But it is an open issue for me. Any comment is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh token should not be expiring. Make sure you are using a refresh token, not an access token. Azure Data Factory will handle internally obtaining and refreshing the access token for you and you will not need to worry about it.

I think that Azure Data Factory BigQuery connector accepts also access token in refresh token -field and I would assume it would behave exactly like in your situation and would not work after access token has expired.

Good documentation on how to authenticate with BigQuery connector can be found here: https://jpda.dev/getting-your-bigquery-refresh-token-for-azure-datafactory-f884ff815a59. In phase **Getting our refresh token** make sure you use value from key `refresh_token`, not `access_token`.

More info on authentication types can be found from Microsoft documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-bigquery#using-user-authentication

Answer (score 0):

This topic is very confusing given the wide variety of advice especially generalized advice that doesn't apply to Bigquery/GA and ADF!   @Veikko would be incorrect in saying it shouldn't expire - Google says differently regarding their tokens.

Refresh token expiration is controlled by the resource and according to Bigquery documentation...
"Access tokens have limited lifetimes. If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain a refresh token. A refresh token allows your application to obtain new access tokens."

I read where this used to support control of the timeout but after Dec 30 2021 it's mandatory at 30 minutes.

Regardless you have to get a refresh token everytime you query Bigquery if you want to use OAuth2.0.  I've read a couple of methods of getting the refresh token but are pretty complicated (at least to me).  My workaround is same as @lalfab....create hosted IR and store the p12 version of the credentials on the VM referenced by the IR there. It works but of course means maintaining a VM and starting/stopping when needed.  I'd love to replace this with OAuth2.0 connection to the Bigquery client id.  Would love to find a simple way of doing this.  But ADF's bigquery linked server also doesn't support dynamic expression to replace refresh token at connect time so it seems like we need to wait until Microsoft makes the bigquery adapter more intelligent.

Answer (score 0):

Well all of these answers are actually correct.

After a lot of research, I think I found the issue.

The issue is that refresh token DO expire, as long as the project is not published yet. The button to publish it, is under the OAuth consent screen.

Please read: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration

I havent tested it yet, but have a strong feeling that this is causing the issues for all of us. Hope it helps!